# How can I get the nearest img tag to an h1 tag using PHP simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, simpledom

I have code that gets the first `h1` tag from a webpage. Now I want to get the first `img` tag that appears either before or after this `h1` tag. How can I do this using PHP Simple HTML DOM?

Comment: you could use preg_match and get the first in the array.

Comment: @Elliott [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Kolink OMG that post is EPIC. I had never read it before. You just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. However, this should probably work:

1. Get the `<h1>` as you have already
2. Get the next sibling. Check if is an image, or if not check if it has an image as a child/descendant
3. Get the previous sibling. Same checks as above.
4. If you haven't found an image yet, get the next sibling ahead, and the previous behind, and repeat until you do or you run out of nodes.
5. If you still have no image, take the parent node of the `<h1>` and repeat the entire process from Step 2.
6. You should now have traversed the entire document, so if you have no result now then there's just no images anywhere.

Trim steps as needed.